# Inverse of a sentence using putchar() in a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

I came into this code reading some slide, just code without explanations, and I can't understand how the invertSeq function works. Especially how the getchar() isn't asking for any input during the function iteration.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void invertSeq(void);

int main() {
    printf("Insert seq: \n");
    invertSeq();
    return 0;
}

void invertSeq(void){
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    if(c == '\n'){
        printf("Inverted seq: ");
        return;
    }
    invertiSeq();
    putchar(c);
    return;
}
```

Comment: `getchar()` doesn't "ask" for input. It just returns the next character of input that's already buffered up.

Comment: If you type a line with 5 characters, each call to `getchar()` will return one of those characters (in the order you typed them), and then the next call will return the `\n` character that ended the line.

Comment: Try stepping through the program with a debugger, you will be enlightened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain this as simply as possible: when a function in a C program calls another function (even itself), it has to “wait” for the function it has called to finish executing its code before proceeding with executing the remaining instructions. So, in this case:

```
1. void invertSeq(void){
2.        int c;
3.       c = getchar();
4.        if(c == '\n'){
5.           printf("Inverted seq: ");
6.           return;
7.       }
8.        invertiSeq();
9.        putchar(c);
10.        return;
11.   }
```

When `invertSeq()` is called by `main()`, the instructions on lines 2 - 7 are executed, and then `invertSeq()` is called. During this time the first character from the input has been read and, if this character is not `\n`, then `invertSeq()` is called (on line 8). Before the instructions on lines 9 and 10 are executed, the recently called `invertSeq()` must execute its instructions. Now, if the next character from the input is not `\n` then `invertSeq()` is called again (keep in mind that at this point the second character from the input has been read). This process, during which `invertSeq()` calls itself several times on line 8, after having executed the instructions from the previous lines, is repeated until `\n` is read from the input. When this happens, the “last” `invertSeq()` called (the one that reads `\n` from the input) executes the instructions on lines 5 and 6 and so prints “Inverted seq: “ and terminates. The “penultimate” `invertSeq()` called (the one that reads the last character of the string) prints the last character by executing `putchar(c)` on line 9 and terminates after executing `return;` on line 10. This process continues until “every” `invertSeq()` executes the instructions on lines 9 and 10, thus printing the characters of the string in the inverse order.